# How do I group and sum grafana metric values after i use regex to transfrom labelnames

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics, regexp-replace

In grafana I have used this query to sum and group a query by path:

`sum by(path) (increase(http_request_duration_seconds_count{applikasjon="kundebetjening-web", path=~"/api-gateway/([^/]+)/.*",environment="prod"}[$__range]))`

After this i used transform and regex functionality in grafana so I can transform the labels from long pathnames like /<apiname>/listusers/user/name to only get the first part of the pathname for example /<apiname>

[image]

The result looks like this image
[image]

As you can see each label is actually a unique path, but because I use regex to shorten the path, I get multiple labelnames on the right side of the chart that have the same name.

How can I combine the labelnames that are the same and sum their value so that instead of getting multiple labelnames with kunde-logg, I only get one and the sum of the metric of all the labelnames that are the same

Ive tried looking in the transform functionality to see if there is a way to combine the labels with no luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate data on Prometheus' side.

You can replace path with its segment using [`label_replace`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#label_replace).

In result your query would look like this:

```
sum by(path_segment) (
  increase(
    label_replace(
      http_request_duration_seconds_count{applikasjon="kundebetjening-web", path=~"/api-gateway/([^/]+)/.*",environment="prod"},
      "path_segment", "$1",
      "path","/api-gateway/([^/]+)/.*"
    ) [$__range : ]
  )
)
```

Also notice that here used [subquery](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#subquery) syntax instead of usual range selector. Difference in that `[$__range]` can be applied only to the vector selectors, while `[$__range : ]` is applicable to results of functions (like `label_replace`) too.